# Make the last line of each paragraph shorter than the rest

Tags: css

In typesetting it is generally considered good practice to make the last line of each paragraph at least a little shorter than the rest.  How do I achieve this using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available as a feature of CSS, however you can work around this limitation using CSS's `::after` pseudo-element like this:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: left;
}

p::after {
  content: '––––––––––––––––––––';
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p style='width: 380px'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
  magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
  commodo consequat.  Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
  anim id est laborum.</p>
```

This will ensure, that the last line of a paragraph is at least 20en shorter, than the other lines.  If there is too much content in the line, the last word will be broken into the next line.

**Note** Make sure your paragraph does not contain any trailing space, since this will cause a linebreak to be allowed between the last word and the pseudo-element.

Comment: If I inherited a project that used this technique, I would immediately remove it.

Comment: While yes this is not ideal, until CSS has something like `:last-line`, then there are unfortunately cases where this hack is needed and works. Especially if you are working within a CMS and maybe can't easily wrap the <p> in a <span> or something which would enable your to add some padding to the end of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

In typesetting, you can predetermine many things - like column width and length. On the web, you can't know what content will be dynamic or be changed - or how the window your site is shown in - may change. If you are working on a graphic layout like a classic 'poster' layout - *for certain breakpoints*, you can use `<br>` line breaks - or split up the copy in different dividers to create the look you want.

Comment: Note, that if you have the ability to predetermine line breaks, this is always the better solution, since it will allow you to use a better line breaking algorithm, than the greedy line breaking employed by browsers.